# How to make a cover that has text of right but in the next page text goes from left to right?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like to have in my essay that on the front page there are text in the right of the side but this does not happen in other pages. How can I fix the code? My effort goes as follows, but the caption "1 beginning" should be aligned to left and the text "dji..." should go from left to right like in a normal Finnish document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \date{}
    
    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-3cm}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[%
    left=3cm,%
    right=3cm,%
    top=2.5cm,%3
    bottom=2.5cm,%
]{geometry}%
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    Title

$\,$

My name
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\vspace{10em}

\end{center}

\raggedleft{Course code essay

Autumn 2022

department

University
}

\newpage
\onehalfspacing
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\noindent \section{beginning} djisdöoiakld ioöj eöio FEIJO ARHOWAHIDFO Ö oa IOJSFDZJOSIDFIOJDWIOAFAOIHDAOHIDFAHIOD
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\raggedleft` behaves like a switch and takes no argument. To use it in a scope (to only apply it to a certain part of your document), you should place curly braces around it and the part of text you want to apply it to. Here, you should use `{\raggedleft Course ... }` instead of `\raggedleft{Course ... }`.